# How to test JSON result from Ruby on Rails functional tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, tdd

How can I assert my [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request and test the JSON output from Ruby on Rails functional tests?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### In Rails >= 5

Use [`ActionDispatch::TestResponse#parsed_body`](https://www.apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionDispatch/TestResponse/parsed_body).

Example:

```
user = @response.parsed_body
assert_equal "Mike", user['name']
```

### In Rails up to 4.x

Use `JSON.parse`, which takes a string as input and returns a Ruby hash that the JSON represents.

Example:

```
user = JSON.parse(@response.body)
assert_equal "Mike", user['name']
```

Comment: With the addition of OpenStruct you can do a little less typing:
`user = JSON.parse(@response.body, object_class: OpenStruct)`
`assert_equal "Mike", user.name`

Answer (score 90):

Rails has JSON support built in:

```
def json_response
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode @response.body
end
```

No need for a plugin

Then you can do something like this:

```
assert_equal "Mike", json_response['name']
```

Comment: For performance, you probably want something like: 
    @json_response ||= ActiveSupport::JSON.decode @response.body

Comment: Alex: Wouldn't that cache the response of the first test and return that in all following JSON tests?

Comment: This will cache the response for all requests within one test function, which may not be a desirable effect. To clarify, it would not cache ACROSS tests.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using RSpec, **json_spec** is worth a look

https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec

Answer (score 4):

Also for short JSON responses you can simply match a string of the JSON to @response.body. This prevents having to rely on yet another gem.

```
assert_equal '{"total_votes":1}', @response.body
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers provides a nice maintainable way to verify a JSON response. I find this one to be the best:

https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema

It provides a nice implementation for the standard [json schema](http://json-schema.org/)

You can write a schema like:

```
schema = {
    "type"=>"object",
    "required" => ["a"],
    "properties" => {
        "a" => {
            "type" => "integer",
            "default" => 42
        },
        "b" => {
            "type" => "object",
            "properties" => {
                "x" => {
                    "type" => "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like: `JSON::Validator.validate(schema, { "a" => 5 })`

Best way to verify it against my android client implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of rails, you can leverage `parsed_body` to get access to this in your tests without any work.

> Calling parsed_body on the response parses the response body based on the last response MIME type.
>
> Out of the box, only :json is supported. But for any custom MIME types you've registered, you can add your own encoders...

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use implicitly the JSON module:

```
assert_equal assigns(:user).to_json, @response.body
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you use JSON.parse to test the JSON, but where you perform that assertion depends on how you are rendering the JSON.

If you are generating the JSON in the controller, you parse the JSON in controller functional tests (as the other answers are showing). If you are rendering JSON, with a view using [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or another gem that takes this approach, then [parse the JSON in the view unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703425/1054831) not the controller functional tests. Unit tests are generally faster to execute and easier to write - e.g., you can build models in-memory rather than create them in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [AssertJson gem](https://github.com/xing/assert_json) for a nice DSL which allows you to check for keys and values which should exist in your JSON response.

Add the gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem 'assert_json'
end
```

This is a quick example how your functional/controller test could look like (the example is an adaption from their [README](https://github.com/xing/assert_json/blob/master/README.md)):

```
class ExampleControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include AssertJson

  def test_my_action
    get :my_action, :format => 'json'
    # => @response.body= '{"key":[{"inner_key":"value1"}]}'

    assert_json(@response.body) do
      has 'key' do
        has 'inner_key', 'value1'
      end
      has_not 'key_not_included'
    end
  end

end
```

You just have to include the `AssertJson` module in your test and use the `assert_json` block where you can check the response for existent and non-existant keys and values. Hint: it's not immediately visible in the [README](https://github.com/xing/assert_json/blob/master/README.md), but to check for a value (e.g. if your action just returns an array of strings) you can do

```
  def test_my_action
    get :my_action, :format => 'json'
    # => @response.body= '["value1", "value2"]'

    assert_json(@response.body) do
      has 'value1'
      has 'value2'
      has_not 'value3'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Very nice. I have just contributed small bugfix to it.

Comment: I recommend against using that GEM. It has a lot of issues.